# Airflow becomes unstable beyond 16 DAGs in parallel

Tags: parallel-processing, airflow-scheduler, airflow

As in the title - I changed the airflow cfg (default -> 16 DAGs in parallel). No I am able to spawn >16 but even 1 above 16 causes problems - airflow "looses" connection with AWS instance and kills the whole process returning failed status (each process takes 2-3 days to complete). I tried to spawn more workers but it didn't seem to help with overall airflow stability.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Unfortunately, there's not information in your post to help answer, please provide more details of your airflow environment, where are you running it? version? backend database? containers? 


https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: hi pyeR_biz airflow ver Version : 1.10.10, running on fargate

Comment: hi pyeR_biz airflow ver Version : 1.10.10, running on fargate
/opt/airflow/airflow.cfg
dags_folder = /opt/airflow/dags
task_log_reader = task

sql_alchemy_pool_enabled = True

sql_alchemy_pool_size = 5